# gRPC Android quickstart code not building due to not finding new method

Tags: java, android, grpc, grpc-java

I'm trying to run through this guide https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/android/ and have succeeded in running it with a Java client, but am having issues with it building because of this:

```
  symbol:   method sayHelloAgain(HelloRequest)
  location: variable stub of type GreeterBlockingStub
/Users/user/code/grpc-java/examples/android/helloworld/app/src/main/java/io/grpc/helloworldexample/HelloworldActivity.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
        reply = stub.sayHelloAgain(request);
                    ^
  symbol:   method sayHelloAgain(HelloRequest)
  location: variable stub of type GreeterBlockingStub
```

I'm seeing that the code in `io.grpc.examples.helloworld.GreeterGrpc` has the `sayHelloAgain` method.  Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never changed the `proto` file that belonged to the Android quickstart, but only the non-Android Java quickstart.

Answer (score 1):

You did not successfully include/compile your proto files. You can look at one of the [Android examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/v1.28.0/examples/android) to figure out the project structure and build configurations.

Comment: Make sure you edit the correct copy of helloworld.proto. You should be editing the app's own copy (in `grpc-java/examples/android/helloworld/app/src/main/proto/helloworld.proto`)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a build issue. Can you delete the generated code/jar from your non-Android Java quickstart and retry?